# Подскажите где обучиться PyQt5 и PyQt3D?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Я учусь программировать на питон. Подскажите Сайты или книги по PyQt5 и PyQt3D с подробным описанием. хочется научиться делать хороший интерфейс

Comment: Публикуйте приложение, которое пробовали сделать. Опишите, что вы хотели сделать и что у вас не получилось.

Comment: Гуглите и ещё раз гуглите...

Comment: Примеры надо публиковать в вопросе, а не приводить ссылку, которая еще и не  работает.